# Stop CKEditor From Making Inline Styles?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I have tried finding a solution on the CK Editor website, but there don't seem to be any answers.

When formatting content within the editor, an image, for example, it applies the attributes (eg. width, height) as an inline style. Eg:
`style="width: 320px; height: 136px;"` instead of `width="320" height="136"`

This makes it impossible to change via a stylesheet.
Obviously using a plain textarea instead is *not* a solution for me, because rich text formatting is essential.

I'm using CKEDitor version 4.1.1.
Anyone know how to change the configuration so that inline styles do not occur?

Thanks!

Comment: This also spoils amp-html and makes it not validating

Answer (score 0):

In the samples that you have downloaded, there's one named "Output HTML", look at its code and you'll see how to use attributes in the images.